# Python socket to replace netcat in OpenTSDB

Tags: python, sockets, opentsdb

I am trying to use python socket instead of netcat to send metric data to OpenTSDB, but got no luck. Can anybody let me know if it is possible to do so?

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("hostname", port))
s.send("put foo 123456789 12.9 host=dummy")
```

`s.send(...)` returns a nonzero value, so I guess the string was indeed sent, it is just that OpenTSDB does not recognize it. I tried to use netcat to send the same string, and it works.

Comment: That code is correct as far as the actual Python goes.  You can verify that it works by running `netcat -l <port>` and pointing your Python code there.  Do you need to add a newline to the end of the command (e.g., `"...host=dummy\n"`)?

Comment: you should `close()` the socket, to make sure that the output buffers are flushed eventually.

Comment: Seems like adding newline does the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OpenTSDB parses line-by-line, so yes you need a `\n` at the end of the string you're sending.